# How to handle conditional features with SVM?

Tags: machine-learning, svm, feature-selection

My dataset contains features that, if present, can have other features associated. To make an example:

```
Feature A: 0/1
Feature B: doesn't exist if A = 0, else: 1/-1
Feature C: doesn't exist if A = 0, else: 1/-1
```

Those features are not absent, they simply don't make sense if "Feature A" is set to 0 so I can't really use data imputation. What is the best way to integrate these features in my dataset? The information is valuable and if possible I would like not to discard it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with linear model (like linear SVM) then simply put "0" for this feature. While -1 and +1 values lead to the use of a particular weight assigned by the model, using "0" means that it will ignore the weight. It becomes much more complex once you consider kernel spaces and I do not think you can make an easy solution for such problem then.